# How to transfer subset of dynamoDB records to a secondary index?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In "The Dynamo Db Book" by Alex brie, in chapter 13.4 talks about how you can transfer a subset of dynamoDB records to a secondary index. Put another way, how you can filter some records so the secondary index can be used as a sort of SQL GROUP BY.

Where is the official API documentation for this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept you are referring to is a Sparse Index.

AWS wrote an [article on the topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html).  However, I want to point out that this is merely a strategy on how you use the table, not a feature of the API.

When you create a Global Secondary Index, you define a set of attributes that DynamoDB will use to copy your items into the index.  You don't do anything special to copy the items into the index yourself, it's something DynamoDB does transparently for you.

If the GSI you've defined doesn't show up on every item in the table, we call the index a "sparse index".  In other words, only a subset of items in your table will be in that index.

I'm sure Alex did a much better job of explaining this than I have, but it's important to note that this isn't something the API does for you.  It's a side effect of which items you include/exclude in the GSI.